# How do I get the value of multiple inputs which created by same component in loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, frontend

I have a component with a single input element and I am creating multiple components by looping. Suppose I have created 3 components by looping and it creates 3 inputs as well. So I do I get the values of all the three input like `input_values = [valueofFirstInput, valueofSecondInput, valueofThirdInput]`

```
function Home(){
  const [multipleQuestions, setMultipleQuestions] = useState([0, 1, 2]);

  return(
     {multipleQuestions.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={data}>
       {<MultipleInputs />}</div>
       )
      })}              
  )
}
```

```
function MultipleInputs() {
  function getinputValues(e) {
    e.target.value;
  }

  return <input onChange={(e) => getinputValues(e)} />;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom input component a controlled input by allowing the value and a callback for when the value changes to be passed in as props. Then, you can store all the input values in state.

```
function Home(){
  const [multipleQuestions, setMultipleQuestions] = useState([0, 1, 2]);
  return multipleQuestions.map((data, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
       <CustomInput value={data} onChange={val => setMultipleQuestions([...multipleQuestions.slice(0, index), val, ...multipleQuestions.slice(index + 1)])}/>
    </div>
  ));
}
function CustomInput({onChange, value}){
    return <input value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}/>;
}
```

Comment: I have multiple other elements as well in MultipleInputs component along with Inputs.

Comment: @devReact That doesn't affect how you manage the state, though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would treat those child components as controlled components which [can share state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components). You would create a handler in the parent component and pass down a reference to it to each input component. They can then call that handler when their `change` event is fired.

In this example I've created a sample dataset which I'm passing into `Home`. Each object in the dataset has an id (which we can use for a key instead of the `map` index), a name, and a label.

In `Home` we create state for the input values. This is an object which pairs a key (the input `name`) with a value.

Here also is the handler which destructures the `name` and `value` from the changed input, and updates the state with that information.

(There is also a `useEffect` which logs the changes to the state as each input is changed so you can see it working.)

When we iterate over the dataset we return an `Input` element passing down the name, type, value (obtained from state), and label as props along with the handler reference. In the `Input` component we attach these props as attributes to the input element, and assign the handler to the `onChange` listener.

```js
const { Fragment, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Home({ questions }) {
  
  // Initialise the state for the inputs
  const [ inputs, setInputs ] = useState({});
  
  // Destructure the name and value from
  // the changed input element, and update
  // the state
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputs(prev => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  }

  // Added simply to show the changing state
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inputs));
  }, [inputs]);

  // `map` over the dataset to produce a
  // series of labels/inputs
  return (
    <main>
      {questions.map(question => {

        const { id, name, label } = question;

        return (
          <Input
            key={id}
            type="text"
            name={name}
            label={label}
            value={inputs[name]}
            handleInput={handleInput}
          />

        );
      })}            
    </main>
  );

}

// Return an input using the props
// passed down to it to identify it
function Input(props) {

  const {
    name,
    label,
    type,
    value,
    handleInput
  } = props;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        id={name}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );

}

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'name', label: 'What is your name?' },
  { id: 2, name: 'age', label: 'How old are you?' },
  { id: 3, name: 'location', label: 'Where are you?' }  
];

const el = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);

root.render(<Home questions={data} />);
```

```css
label { display: block; }
.as-console-wrapper { height: 25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```